# javascript / jquery - avoid repeating evaluation of a conditional

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, jquery

I currently have a conditional running in jquery's scroll event, which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense since it will only execute once. I was wondering if there is any way to ensure that the conditional will only be evaluated once.

here's my code:

```
$window.scroll(function() {
  if (s1_doAnimate == true){
    s1_doAnimate = false;
  }
})
```

Comment: Is this a part of the code in scroll event or is this the only operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(window).one('scroll', function(){
...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can unbind the handler once the condition has been met;

```
$window.scroll(function foo /* give the function a name */ () {
  if (s1_doAnimate == true){
    s1_doAnimate = false;

    // Unbind the handler referenced by the name...
    $window.off(foo);
  }
})
```

Comment: Wouldn’t this create a new function for each trigger? Maybe it’s better to store `foo` outside the handler? Just curious...

Comment: @David: No, the declaration is only processed once (*before* the function expression is passed to the `scroll()` function). IE < 9 will create 2 functions for it though ([more](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html));